# Solr / Lucene: Filter to Convert "Word-Numbers" to Numbers

Tags: search, filter, solr, lucene, indexing

I'm using Solr as a search frontend to a large corpus of music artist / track information.

Is there a filter or other way to convert "word-numbers" like "five" to their equivalent number ("5") at index time in Lucene / Solr?

As an example, searching for "Ben Folds Five" should return "Ben Folds 5" as a result.

There is the PatternReplaceFilterFactory but doing that all in a regex seems like overkill.

Comment: You'll want to use synonyms. This can be done at index time, query time, or both.

Comment: I'd do it at index time with a Synonym Analyzer. I'm not sure what that's mapped to in solr, but someone will know.

Comment: @Tass Thanks for the hints guys; I looked into the [SynonymFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) but it seems to require a text file with explicit mappings, which would be unwieldy for all possible numbers.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This means that you must do it manually in a custom TokenFilter.

Comment: @Spoom, it would definitely be unwieldy for all possible numbers but how many numbers are we talking about in this case?

Comment: Bumping this up. Is there any inbuilt feature available for this in Solr. I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that works (I used it in the past):

```
import java.util.*;

class ConvertWordToNumber {

    public static String WithSeparator(long number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            return "-" + WithSeparator(-number);
        }
        if (number / 1000L > 0) {
            return WithSeparator(number / 1000L) + ","
                    + String.format("%1$03d", number % 1000L);
        } else {
            return String.format("%1$d", number);
        }
    }

    private static String[] numerals = { "zero", "one", "two",
            "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
            "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",
            "seventeen", "eighteen", "ninteen", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
            "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "hundred" };

    private static long[] values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
            13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };

    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(numerals));

    public static long parseNumerals(String text) throws Exception {
        long value = 0;
        String[] words = text.replaceAll(" and ", " ").split("\\s");
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!list.contains(word)) {
                throw new Exception("Unknown token : " + word);
            }

            long subval = getValueOf(word);
            if (subval == 100) {
                if (value == 0)
                    value = 100;
                else
                    value *= 100;
            } else
                value += subval;
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static long getValueOf(String word) {
        return values[list.indexOf(word)];
    }

    private static String[] words = { "trillion", "billion", "million", "thousand" };
    private static long[] digits = { 1000000000000L, 1000000000L, 1000000L, 1000L };

    public static long parse(String text) throws Exception {
        text = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\-,]", " ").replaceAll(" and "," ");
        long totalValue = 0;
        boolean processed = false;
        for (int n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
            int index = text.indexOf(words[n]);
            if (index >= 0) {
                String text1 = text.substring(0, index).trim();
                String text2 = text.substring(index + words[n].length()).trim();

                if (text1.equals(""))
                    text1 = "one";

                if (text2.equals(""))
                    text2 = "zero";

                totalValue = parseNumerals(text1) * digits[n] + parse(text2);
                processed = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (processed)
            return totalValue;
        else
            return parseNumerals(text);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number in words : ");
        String numberWordsText = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Value : " + 
                ConvertWordToNumber.WithSeparator(
                ConvertWordToNumber.parse(numberWordsText)));
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Interview-Questions/13787-Java-program---convert-words-into-numbers.html).

You can use it to build your own Solr filter.
Here's a decent post about that:

http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/building-a-solr-text-filter-for-normalizing-data/

Please contribute it to the Solr community when it's done. 
You can write your own wiki page.

To start, just follow link similar to this one:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrWordToNumberConverter

Comment: Thanks!  I will work on this at some point.  Currently I've worked around the issue by getting fuzzy search working with a lower threshold for matching.  If I make such a filter I will definitely contribute it back.

Comment: @Marko, Is this possible with solr config or any analyzer?
Because if i want to use this into multiple language than it will very difficult and code is also too large with many language.  
So might be *performance* is break our her.