# How do I configure Elasticsearch to match either number or "spelled-out" number?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

If I have a document in Elasticsearch where one of its fields contains the term "ten", is there an analyzer/tokenizer which will allow matching that document when searching for either "10" or "ten"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so, no.  The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806103/solr-lucene-filter-to-convert-word-numbers-to-numbers), I believe, still stands for both ElasticSearch and Solr, unfortunately.

If you don't need a lot of numbers matched (say, sticking only to numbers commonly spelled out), though, this is fairly simple to set up with a [SynonymFilter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html), like:

```
"filter" : {
    "synonym" : {
        "type" : "synonym",
        "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
    }
}
```

with a mapping in "synonyms.txt" like:

```
zero, aught => 0
quarter => .25
half => .5
one => 1
two => 2
three => 3
four => 4
five => 5
six => 6
seven => 7
eight => 8
nine => 9
ten => 10
eleven => 11
twelve, dozen => 12
twenty => 20
thirty => 30
```

and so on.

Comment: I thought this might be a possibility, thanks for confirming that! I'll be giving this a try. It's too bad what we're after isn't built-in. One day...